# AWS RHEL7 missing packages

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, repository, yum

I've been stuck trying to install a LAMP web server on my virtual machine running RHEL7 because the packages appear to be missing!

I've installed and enabled various repositories but I still can't see the packages I want.

I'll take you through the steps:-

1) `sudo yum clean`
2) `sudo yum update`
3) `sudo yum install httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd`

Then I get the following:-

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package httpd24 available.
No package php56 available.
No package mysql55-server available.
No package php56-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

4) `sudo yum repolist all`

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
repo id                                                          repo name                                                                status
epel/x86_64                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                           enabled: 10,171
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                   disabled
epel-source                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                  disabled
epel-testing/x86_64                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64                 disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug         disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64                                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Source        disabled
nodesource/x86_64                                                Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                         enabled:     85
nodesource-source                                                Node.js for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                         disabled
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64                        Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7          enabled:      6
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-extras/7Server/x86_64              Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra Debug (Debug RPMs)               disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-optional/7Server/x86_64            Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional Debug (Debug RPMs)            disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-rh-common/7Server/x86_64           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common Debug (Debug RPMs)           disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-rhscl/7Server/x86_64               Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL Debug (Debug RPMs)               disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-supplementary/7Server/x86_64       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary Debug (Debug RPMs)       disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras/7Server/x86_64                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra(RPMs)                            enabled:    213
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional/7Server/x86_64                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (RPMs)                        enabled:  8,617
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)                                 enabled: 10,869
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-debug/7Server/x86_64            Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Debug (Debug RPMs)                     disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-source/7Server/x86_64           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (SRPMs)                                disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common/7Server/x86_64                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (RPMs)                       enabled:    186
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl/7Server/x86_64                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL (RPMs)                           disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-extras/7Server/x86_64             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra (SRPMs)                          disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-optional/7Server/x86_64           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (SRPMs)                       disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-rh-common/7Server/x86_64          Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (SRPMs)                      disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-rhscl/7Server/x86_64              Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL (SRPMs)                          disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-supplementary/7Server/x86_64      Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary (SRPMs)                  disabled
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-supplementary/7Server/x86_64             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary (RPMs)                   disabled
rpmforge                                                         RHEL 7Server - RPMforge.net - dag                                        enabled:    245
rpmforge-extras                                                  RHEL 7Server - RPMforge.net - extras                                     disabled
rpmforge-testing                                                 RHEL 7Server - RPMforge.net - testing                                    disabled
repolist: 30,392
```

5) I also tried `sudo yum –-enablerepo=epel install httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd` - but this didn't do anything!

What am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These packages are not correctly named.
You can use *'yum search'* to find the right package. For example:

```
yum search httpd
```

Will return lots of packages including :

```
httpd.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
```

Then you can get informations about this package with *'yum info'* :

```
yum info httpd.x86_64
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Installed Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.15
Release     : 47.el6_7.1
Size        : 2.9 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-6-server-rpms
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and     extensible
            : web server.
```

Here the version is 2.2.15.

Using the --enable-repo=epel option is useless as this repo is enable in your repositories.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This helped :)